# .htaccess setting in laravel setup for both subdomain and domain

Tags: laravel

i install laravel project on my main domain and i want host another project on subdomain but when i visit subdomain its show 500 error

how to fix it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !
^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ $1
[L]
</IfModule>
```

When I first tried accessing the subdomain I was
getting a 503 to many redirect requests error. If the
.htaccess-root file is removed the subdomain displays
the directory contents. I then started fiddling with
writing another .htaccess-root file. Everytime I get
the domain working the subdomain breaks and Vice-
Versa. Below are some of the things ive been trying. I
even thought that maybe I should remove the
public/.htaccess and try do all the rewriting at the
root level for both domains but I cant get anything to
work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This set of config works for me:

### /var/www/website-a/public/.htaccess

### /var/www/website-b/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

### /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website-a/public
        ServerName domaina.com
        ServerAlias domaina-alias.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/website-a/public>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride all
                CheckSpelling ON
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website-b
        ServerName subdomain.domaina.com
        ServerAlias subdomain-b.domaina.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/website-b>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride all
                CheckSpelling ON
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Give it a try? and then run `service apache2 reload`
If you still get 500 errors, please check Apache log (located in `/var/log/apache2` if you are using Ubuntu)
see what's in `error.log`

Also check error log of laravel in `(project root)/storage/logs/`